# c++ template function error: variable or field 'swapAdjacent' declared void

Tags: c++

This is my List class

```
template <typename Object>
class List {
    public:
        class iterator {
            ...
        };
    ....
};
```

This is my function

```
template <typename Object>
void swapAdjacent(List<Object>::iterator & itrA, List<Object>::iterator & itrB) {

}
```

After compiling, turns out following error

> error: variable or field 'swapAdjacent' declared void

Why it can't work?

If I change my code to following, it can be work

```
void swapAdjacent(List<int>::iterator & itrA, List<int>::iterator & itrB) {

}
```

I need help; why the first function can't work?

Comment: Compiles fine for me. What is your compiler and how are you callling swapAdjacent()?

Comment: compiler:
g++ (i686-posix-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 5.2.0
I did not call the function yet.
When compiling, the error occurs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems like an odd compiler error, but it looks like your issue is that you need to tell the compiler that the dependent name `List<Object>::iterator` names a type. You do this using the `typename` keyword:

```
template <typename Object>
void swapAdjacent(typename List<Object>::iterator & itrA, 
                  typename List<Object>::iterator & itrB) {

}
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) for more information about the `typename` keyword.

For brevity, you could just use the iterator as the template parameter, which would win you automatic deduction as well:

```
template <typename Iterator>
void swapAdjacent(Iterator & itrA, Iterator & itrB) {

}
```

Comment: Also change the template to <class Object> should work too

Comment: @DanielSanchez that doesn't make a difference; `class` vs. `typename` is a purely stylistic choice unless we're talking about template template parameters pre-C++17.

Comment: then as list itself is a template you would not need to add typename before, I cant try it right now, but I think that using the typename in the template is forcing it to spread over the definitions

Comment: @DanielSanchez that's not right. If you put `class` you would still need to use `typename` to mark the dependent name as a type. `[temp.param]/2:` "There is no semantic difference between `class` and `typename` in a *template-parameter*."

Comment: @TartanLlama ok, just tested it, i was mixing std::list with List, but anyway, i dont understant it properly, why have you to declare the typenames once more in the template for an existing type already? may we move to a chat please, it really annoys me. :/

Comment: ok, was reading the link post and everything is cristal clear there, thanks :D